# "House-like" border in css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a div with a simple border:

```
border: 10px solid #642850;
```

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid #642850;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I'm looking to create a shape like this:

[image: Example]

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one : 
http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/L5zz1hak/2/

```css
.sq {
  border: 10px solid #642850;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.tl {
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: -36px;
  border-left: 10px solid #642850;
  border-top: 10px solid #642850;
  height: 76px;
  width: 76px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sq">
  <div class="tl"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### CSS

By using a `pseudo-element` and using css transforms, the desired shape can be accomplished.

```css
div {
  background: white;
  border: 10px solid #642850;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  positioN: relative;
}
div::before {
  margin-top: -52px;
  border: 10px solid #642850;
  background: white;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### SVG

An alternative could be to use SVG to generate the shape you want. SVG's are responsive and well supported across browsers.

```html
<svg width="50%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <polygon points="2,25 2,98 98,98 98,25 50,2z" fill="white" stroke-width="2" stroke="#642850"></polygon>
  <polyline points="2,25 98,25" stroke="#642850" stroke-width="2"></polyline>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
.b{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.b div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    content:"";
    border:10px solid red;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
.a{
    width:180px;
    height:200px;
    border:10px solid red;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b"><div></div></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: Dude, sory, but actually I used Sachiks variant. It fit better to my case.

Comment: @SergeyScopin it's okay i too felt that his was better

Answer (score 2):

With one div and using generated content:

```css
div {width:100px; height:100px; border:5px solid red; position:relative; margin-top:50px}
div:after,div:before {content:""; position:absolute; border:55px solid red; border-color:transparent transparent red transparent; border-width:40px 55px; bottom:105px; left:-5px}
div:after {border-color:transparent transparent white transparent; border-width:34px 48px; left:2px}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```css
.roof {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(499px - 48px);
  left: 899px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 120px solid #f00;
  border-top: 120px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.roofCovering {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(499px - 48px + 5px);
  left: 909px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid #fff;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.house {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(499px - 48px + 58px);
  left: 874px;
  height: 165px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 5px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="roof"></div>
<div class="roofCovering"></div>
<div class="house"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).